# Flask: A RESTful API and SocketIO Server

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, flask-socketio

**Background**

I am trying to create a simple REST API using the Flask-RESTful extension. This API will be working primarily to manage the CRUD and authentication of users for a simple service.

I am also trying to create a few web sockets using the Flask-SocketIO extension that these users will be able to connect to and see real-time updates for some data related to other people using the service. As such, I need to know that these users are authenticated and authorized to connect to certain sockets.

**Problem**

However, I'm having a bit of trouble getting set up. It seems like I am not able to have these two components (the REST API and SocketIO server) work together on the same Flask instance. The reason I say this is because when I run the following, either the REST API or the SocketIO server will work, but not both:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)

api = Api(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

# some test resources for the API and
# a test emitter statement for the SocketIO server
# are added here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
    socketio.run(app, port=5005)
```

**Question**

Is the typical solution for this type of setup to have two distinct instances of Flask going at the same time? For instance, would my SocketIO server have to make requests to my REST API in order to check to see that a specific user is authenticated/authorized to connect to a specific socket?

Comment: What happens if you *just* use `socketio.run(app, port=5005)` and try to hit the REST API on port 5005?

Comment: @SeanVieira For some reason, that works fine... I suppose I'll just keep my API and sockets on the same port then

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You just want to run `socketio.run(app, port=5005)` and hit the REST API on port 5005.

The reason this works is because under the hood, Flask-SocketIO is running an evented webserver based on gevent (or with the 1.0 release, also eventlet) - this server handling the websocket requests directly (using the handlers you register via the `socketio.on` decorator) and is passing on the non-websocket requests to Flask.

The reason your code *wasn't* working is because both `app.run` and `socketio.run` are *blocking* operations.  Whichever one ran first was looping, waiting for connections, never allowing the second to kick off.  If you really *needed* to run your websocket connections on a different port you'd need to spawn either the socketio or the app `run` call on a different process.

Comment: Great answer, but I wanted to note that Flask-SocketIO is about to break the exclusive dependency on gevent. Development release 1.0a1 of the extension can use gevent, eventlet or even plain Werkzeug (though the latter runs without WebSocket support).